# Admin is disabled because insecure channel

Tags: python, web2py, pafy

I am using web2py in pythonanywhere.com for creating my webapp but when i import the module name pafy and using it in controllers of web2py and then running my app it shows Admin is disabled because insecure channel.
Code which i wrote there is given below.
below is default.py script in controller folder

```
def first():
    return dict()

def second():
    import pafy
    dlink = request.vars.q
    video = pafy.new("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odoSnOD6xRA")
    return dict(message="video")
```

Comment: Are you saying you receive an error ticket, but when you click on it, you receive the message about Admin? The Admin app is only available via local requests or HTTPS. Does the error occur when running on your local machine? If so, it might be easier to view the error ticket there.

Comment: Error was occured in pythonanywhere.com hosting and thanks for the help. Problem is solved using https:// in the starting of address

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to see an error ticket.

Try to add https to the URL.